# event not emitting at all in solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3-providers

i have function which needs to transfer some funds and then emit an event. Here is the code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Rental {
    struct PaidRent {
        uint id;
        uint value;
    }
    event RentPaid(bool Status);
    PaidRent[] public paidrents;
    function payRent(uint _rent) public payable returns(bool status) {
        owner.send(_rent);
        paidrents.push(PaidRent({
            id : paidrents.length + 1,
            value : _rent
        }));
        RentPaid(true);
        return true;
    }
}
```

in my angular service i am calling this function and then watching for the event. following is sevice code

```
paymyRent(contractInstance, rent) {
    this.contractevent = contractInstance.RentPaid();
    this.contractevent.watch(function (error, result) {
      if (!error) {
        console.log(result.args);
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
    contractInstance.payRent(rent, {from: this.web3.eth.accounts[0],
      gas:1000000, value: this.web3.toWei(0.01, "ether")});
  }
```

but this event is never emitted. Any idea what is problem here?

Comment: You carved out too much, so your example doesn't compile.

Comment: Is owner a contract? In that case: does it have a fallback function? It should be payable and the only thing it can/should do is emit an event or nothing. This is because send() passes along a very small amount of gas to the recipient

Comment: @henkiedoodle no. owner is not a contract. it is an account address.

Comment: @RobHitchens please explain a little more.

Comment: Can you check if the transaction receipt to determine if it has succeeded? No events will be generated if the transaction has failed.